# How to prevent WPF datagrid from auto select row upon scrolling

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

below is my datagrid's definition:

```
<DataGrid
    Name="ODataGrid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    AlternationCount="2"
    HeadersVisibility="All"
    IsReadOnly="True"                               
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Background="#EBF0F0"
    AlternatingRowBackground="#E9E8EF"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#7F7F7F"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="#7F7F7F"
    SelectedItem="{Binding vmItem}"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource ODataGridCellStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding vmResults}"
    Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=BaseGrid}">
```

Below are the steps I took to get the error.

1. The first row was selected by default.
2. I select another row in the datagrid.
3. I do a sort by clicking on one of the column header.
4. I do a scroll by dragging the vertical scroll bar.
5. The initial first row was somehow auto selected.
6. So now, there are 2 rows being selected.

Why this behaviour? Anyway to prevent the auto select on scroll? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that DataGrid dont have set SelectionMode property Set dg.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended will select more than one row selectd ?

Comment: Hi, my SelectionMode has to be Extended, hence I cannot set it to Single, although that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
EnableRowVirtualization="False"
```

In the datagrid properties.

Answer (score -2):

add this property in datagrid

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```